# ошибка DNS для некоторых доменов

Tags: хостинг, dns

Добрый день!

Несколько месяцев мучаюсь с DNS для нескольких своих доменов.

Основная часть моих доменов зарегистрирована через webnames.ru.
При этом с бОльшая часть нормально работают через DNS сервера регистратора (ns1.nameself.com, ns2.nameself.com), но почему-то не все.

Основная проблема у меня с двумя доменами:
dolgoozern.ru
chery-shop.ru

Ранее я уже пробовал переносить DNS для этих доменов на другой платный хостинг (fornex.com), но это не помогло.

Менять регистратора совсем не хочется, так как это слишком муторно, да и нет уверенности что поможет.

В итоге проблему с chery-shop.ru недавно удалось решить переносом DNS на бесплатный DNS хостинг.

Однако, для домена dolgoozern.ru такой фикус не прошел (правда я его перенес только дня три назад).

Тесты доступности для обоих доменов: http://www.charkov.ru/temp/ping-admin.html

Вчера выяснилось, что домен dolgoozern.ru почему-то не резолвается Google public DNS (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4). Может в этом проблема? Однако, как ее решить даже не представляю...

Прошу подсказать в какую сторону мне можно еще покопать.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: проблема ещё актуальна?

Comment: Проблема решилась отключением DNSSEC в настройках зоны DNS. То ли он некорректно работает в webnames, то ли DNS-клиенты некорректно обрабатывают запросы. Скорее первое